# Per partes velocities

Tags: integration

I compute the integral 
$$\int_0^T \dot v^2 dt$$

Could you explain to me this integration, please?

$$\int_0^T\dot v^2dt=\int_0^T(v\dot v-v\ddot v)dt$$

I have on the right-hand-side $$v \dot v - \int \ddot v \dot v dt$$

Comment: the final integral on your right hand side would be $\int \ddot{v}vdt$ which matches their second term on the right hand side.

Comment: And why please?

Comment: because you do by parts differentiating $\dot{v}$ and integrating $\dot{v}$

Comment: it should read $\int_0^T \dot{v}^2 dt = v \dot{v} - \int_0^T v \ddot{v} dt$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write for clarity the final expression with the arguments:

$\int_0^{T}\dot{v}^2(t)dt=\dot{v}(T)v(T)-\dot{v}(0)v(0)-\int_0^{T}\ddot{v}(t)v(t)dt$

which is intendend to be an integration by parts.